# Python building standalone application with py2app

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, py2app

Trying to build my application using `py2app`. Created and wrote `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = ['images/ship.png', 'images/ufo.png', 'fonts/a_lcdnova.ttf']
APP_NAME = "Alien Invasion"

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'includes': ('pygame'),
    'iconfile': 'images/ship.icns'
}
setup(
    name=APP_NAME,
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

In this case `main.py` imports:

```
from Button import Button
from Enemy import Enemy
from Ship import Ship
from random import randint
import pygame
import sys
```

In the performance getting the right `Alien Invasion.app` with the desired icon, but at startup I get a white screen. On the Internet I could not find how to configure `setup.py` :( Please help!

Comment: Regarding the configuration of ``setup.py``. Here is some documentation on writing the setup script: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was to specify the full path to the resource files. It was necessary to specify only a folder, like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = ['images', 'fonts']
APP_NAME = "Alien Invasion"

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'includes': ('pygame'),
    'iconfile': 'images/ship.icns'
}
setup(
    name=APP_NAME,
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```